# want to redirect inside the axios code reacr

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
axios
    .post('http://oud-zerobase.me/api/v1/users/signUp', toSent)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        /**redirect to home  */
        const authToken = response.data.token;
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', authToken);
        console.log('token', authToken);
        console.log(response);
        /**redirect to home */
      } else if (response.status === 400) {
        errorMassage = response.statusText;
      } else if (response.status === 401) {
        /**Unauthorized */
        errorMassage = response.statusText;
      }
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        prevState.formErrors.mainError = errorMassage;
        return prevState;
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
```

here I send the `accessToken` to a function outside I want to redirect the page when it successful

Answer (score 2):

you can use `hooks` in `react-router-dom` to push your route:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

let history = useHistory();
history.push("/ROUTE_NAME");
```